# Errors after updating to GCC 12

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc12

I have a project where I'm using the [datetimepp](https://github.com/coin-au-carre/datetimepp) library and it has been working fine. However I recently did a `pacman -Syu` and updated gcc. I then compiled the project (which had been compiling properly before that) and compiled it. I got multiple errors complaining "default argument redefinition"

```
datetimepp/datetime.h:311:96: error: redefinition of default argument for ‘typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<_Tp>::value>::type* <anonymous>’
  311 | template<class Scalar, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<Scalar>::value>::type* = nullptr>
      |                                                                                                ^~~~~~~
datetimepp/datetime.h:73:96: note: original definition appeared here
   73 | template<class Scalar, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<Scalar>::value>::type* = nullptr>
      |                                                                                                ^~~~~~~
datetimepp/datetime.h:323:90: error: redefinition of default argument for ‘typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<_Tp>::value>::type* <anonymous>’
  323 | template<class Scalar, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Scalar>::value>::type* = nullptr>
      |                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
datetimepp/datetime.h:76:90: note: original definition appeared here
   76 | template<class Scalar, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Scalar>::value>::type* = nullptr>
      |                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
datetimepp/datetime.h:335:96: error: redefinition of default argument for ‘typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<_Tp>::value>::type* <anonymous>’
  335 | template<class Scalar, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<Scalar>::value>::type* = nullptr>
      |                                                                                                ^~~~~~~
datetimepp/datetime.h:79:96: note: original definition appeared here
   79 | template<class Scalar, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<Scalar>::value>::type* = nullptr>
      |                                                                                                ^~~~~~~
datetimepp/datetime.h:342:90: error: redefinition of default argument for ‘typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<_Tp>::value>::type* <anonymous>’
  342 | template<class Scalar, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Scalar>::value>::type* = nullptr>
      |                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
datetimepp/datetime.h:82:90: note: original definition appeared here
   82 | template<class Scalar, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Scalar>::value>::type* = nullptr>
```

Just to confirm that the program was indeed working before I updated, I rolled back the gcc update and the program compiled successfully.

Is this a problem with my program that I should fix, or is it a problem with g++?

Comment: The behavior of GCC 12 is correct. Your library redefines the default template argument for some templates, which is not allowed in the C++ standard.

Comment: It is a [recently fixed bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50370) in gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default arguments can only be specified at either declaration or definition but in your case you've specified them at both places.

```
void foo(int x = 10);
void foo(int x = 10){} // error. redefinition of default arg
void foo(int x){}
foo(); // ok. default arg is 10
```

So you should remove them from either declaration or definition, definition would be preferred because in between definition and declaration, you wouldn't be able to use those default arguments.

```
void foo(int x);
foo(); // error. no default arg
void foo(int x = 10){}
foo(); // ok
```